# modinfo finding the wrong driver

Tags: drivers

I am trying to change my WiFi driver, per suggestions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek#PCI). I found [this repository](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver) that claims to have what I want. Upon running the install script, everything goes well, except for the last step, where it uses `modinfo` to check if the new drivers are being used. It says that the old driver is still being used.

After some investigation, I found that `modinfo` is the source of the script's report. I found that I now have two drivers with the same name, only one of which I want to use. They are located at:

The old one:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
```

and the new one:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
```

`modinfo` is reporting the old one, and I am trying to use the new one instead. The [man page for `modinfo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/modinfo.8.html) just says that it searches for the file name in `/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic`. If I pass the more specific location, it can be made to find either driver.

I imagine that this means that the new driver is not being used, and I would like to change that. I have looked up some solutions, but they tend to include phrases like "you could end up with an unbootable system," so I have not fiddled too much. I am far from an expert on drivers...

So my question is: how do I get the new driver working in a situation like this?

---

In response to comments:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8192ce
```

yields

```
rmmod rtl8192ce
rmmod rtl8192c_common
rmmod rtl_pci
rmmod rtlwifi
rmmod mac80211
rmmod cfg80211
```

and

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

yields

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko ips=0 fwlps=0 swenc=1
```

Incidentally, running those commands killed the wifi, necessitating a reboot (this is probably a manifestation of the issue I was trying to solve by changing drivers?).

Comment: What is the output of `modprobe -rv rtl8192ce` and `modprobe -v rtl8192ce`? [please edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/405489/edit)

Comment: I added the info in an edit.

Comment: Remove the `firmware-realtek`  package then run `modprobe -rv rtl8192ce`

Comment: Does the output of `modprobe -rv rtl8192ce` changed?

Comment: I tried removing firmware-realtek using apt (I am running Ubuntu), and it did not find anything. Also, "locate firmware-realtek" did not return anything. Any hints on where else I could be looking for that package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the kernel modules installed from the git repo:

unload the modules :

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8192ce
```

Load the modules from

`/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/`:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko ips=0 fwlps=0 swenc=1
```

Comment: I followed this advice, and it might have worked, but I am not sure. Bumps: - changed to _ in rtl8192c-common.ko and rtl_pci.ko did not exist. The internet turned on and off when I did this and is working. Modinfo still reports the old driver. I'll try restarting to see if that changes anything. Should the changes you suggested be persistent across reboots?

Comment: Same thing happened after a reboot. I'm assuming that this means that modinfo is not the correct way to tell what driver is being used in this case?

Comment: @ZachBoyd and `modinfo /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko` it will show you the required info about the new kernel module.

Comment: That gives the new driver, as expected. When I do modinfo rtl8192ce, if gives the old one.

Comment: How do I know if the new driver is being used versus the old one?

Comment: The new driver is currently used   , to avoid any confusion we are using the command `insmod` to load the driver recently compiled , the `modinfo` (maybe , i am not sure) use the default and the old path to give the module kernel info.

Comment: I agree. Eventually I decided to make the old driver a sym link to the new one and put your answer in a startup script, which fixed most of the issues. Modinfo is still not working but this is not a big deal. Thanks for your help!